# Select tag not able to capture the value in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Code:-

```
 const removeRedundant = (array) => {
        return array.filter(function (item, pos) {
            return array.indexOf(item) === pos;
        })

    }


<td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>

                                        <select id="SelectFocus" value={playdata.ChannelName} tabIndex={-1}
                                            className="btn_primary"
                                            onChange={(e) => { setPlayer(e.target.value, playdata.idx); setHighlightPlayer(e.target.value, playdata.idx) }}   >
                                            {/* <option value="select">{playdata.ChannelName}</option> */}
                                            {Channelname.map((val, id) => {
                                                // setCHANNEL = val;                                            
                                                //console.log("val", val,id)
                                                return (

                                                    <Fragment key={id}>
                                                        {removeRedundant([...val, playdata.ChannelName]).map((val1) => {
                                                            //console.log(val1,index1);
                                                            return <option value={val1} key={val1}>{val1}</option>;
                                                        })}
                                                    </Fragment>
                                                )
                                            })
                                            }

                                        </select>
                                    </td>
```

when i try to click the 1 default value it's not showing in console.log but when i click the another value it's show the value but i want to receive the both value when click

[image]

as show in image when there is A value then B is show in Console whne i click but when i click the A value its does not work
how can i do in select tag ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you, but am I correct to assume that, when you click the first time, it doesn't console log it, the 2nd time and hereafter it works?

If so, that is because setting a state is internally asynchronous and cannot be 'awaited' either.